# Finish infinite iterations cycle and stop the animation with CSS

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I have an animation that has an infinite iterations count:

```
.spinner {
  animation: spinnerAnimation 2s linear infinite;
}
```

What I want is to make the animation finish the current animation cycle and stop it on a button click (not really on a button click, but this is to make things easier to understand):

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".spinner").addClass("stop");
})
```

This will add a `stop` class to the spinner:

```
.spinner.stop {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

It doesn't work really smooth, but I don't care about smoothness much in this case:

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/OXZvdm

The only problem is that *this won't stop the animation in IE edge*, i.e. things don't work in IE (versions that support animations). Any ideas?

PS: `animation-play-state: pause;` *is not* what I need, because this won't make the animation finish the current animation cycle, but pause it in its current position instead.

PSS: I am really looking for a CSS only solution, i.e. make it work inside `.spinner.stop{}`.

Comment: U can try to add the style attribute inside the element

Comment: @Deka87, did you check the answer?

Comment: @Dekel, thanks for the answer, Dekel! Yeah, that's what I need!

Comment: You are more than welcome :) a voteup will also be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You had a problem with the name of your keyframe name - `spinnerAnimation` vs `preloaderAnimation`
2. The only way I was able to set IE to stop the animation was to set `animation: none;` inside the `.stop` class:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".spinner").addClass("stop");
})
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  background: green;
  animation: spinnerAnimation 2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner.stop {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinnerAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinnerAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner"></div>
<button>Stop spinner</button>
```