# Css keyframe loop, finish iteration of animation on element with multiple animations

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

I have a css keyframe animation which loops.
`animation-iteration-count: infinite`
Now when I click a button I want the animation to finish the current loop and then stop.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061209/stopping-a-css-animation-but-letting-its-current-iteration-finish) question seems related, but `animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration` callbacks don't seem to be called at the end of the keyframe animation, but more often.

> EDIT: This turned out to *almost* be the correct solution, only that it can't handle multiple animations. For more info see my answer below.

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/2L04xgbn/) shows my animation, and on hover I want to try to finish the current loop and then stop. This includes the answer proposed by @Alex Gru, It doesn't work if one wait for the animation to loop multiple times and then hover you can see the animation **jumps**. If it has not looped a full iteration and I set `animation-iteration-count: 1` it works as intended.

Comment: _"I've tried using webkitAnimationIteration to count iterations, but the count doesn't seems to directly correlation with the amount of loops so far."_ - meaning what, exactly? Please don't give us just such a more than vague statement that you tried something and it didn't work, but be explicit - [mre] of what you tried, plus a proper problem description.

Comment: `document.getElementById("animated-thing").addEventListener("webkitAnimationIteration", function (event) {`
But the function is not called when the loop finished but more often in between.

Comment: This is not necessarily relevant to the question just a thing i tried.

Comment: I've re framed the question. This time not including what didn't work.
There is no need for a minimal example, since explaining false approaches - might aid people helping - but certainly complicated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out why it didn't work. There is some additional information in how I've managed to get it to work after all, that I'll explain here.

It was my **fault** because there is another animation attached sub element:

```
<div id="a1"> <-- Main animation that should finish the loop
  <div id="a2"></div> <-- sub animation that should not be finished
</div>
```

That was the reason why the animation call backs where triggered more often than expected. **But:** I found out that I can filter by animation name!

```
$("#a1").on('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function(e) {
/* this triggers not only when animation of #a1 iterated but also if animation of #a2 iterated */
 let animation_name = e.originalEvent.animationName;
if(animation_name == "animation1name"){
 //This will only trigger if the correct animation iterated
}
});
```

I hope this solution can help someone who tries to **handle multiple looping animations applied to one element (or sub element)**

Thanks to everyone else who helped! ( I adjusted the question title in order to highlight what the problem actually was )

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal solution for your use case:

First, add another class `.stop` when you want to finish the animation.

```
  $(".target").addClass("stop");
```

Define the following css styling, which finishes the current cycle and stops the animation afterwards.

```css
.target.stop {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation: none;
}
```

Also see: [Finish infinite iterations cycle and stop the animation with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148017/finish-infinite-iterations-cycle-and-stop-the-animation-with-css)

Comment: `animation: none` stops it immediately. If I use `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1` only It works, but only if the animation didn't play a full iteration yet.
If the animation looped e.g.: 3 times, if i then set ` -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1` it just **jumps** to the end of the animation

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle showing the problem. Here I add the `stop` class on hover.
If you wait for the animation to loop more then once and then hover you can see it **jump**

Comment: Basically I need a way to set  `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: current-count + 1`